# Reference one RoslynPad script from another

Tags: roslynpad

What I'd like to do is reference one script from another.

One way to make this happen might be using assemblies.  RoslynPad allows compiling a script into an assembly.  Here is what I have tried so far.

Script A, which is compiled to SOME_PATH\thing.dll

```
    class Thing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Script B

```
    #r "SOME_PATH\thing.dll"

    using static Program;

    var t = new Thing();
    t.Name = "TEST";
    t.Name.Dump();
```

This gives the error "The type or namespace 'Thing' could not be found..." so I tried the following.

```
    #r "SOME_PATH\thing.dll"

    var t = new Program.Thing();
    t.Name = "TEST";
    t.Name.Dump();
```

This gave the following error "The type name 'Thing' does not exist in the type 'Program'".

Is there a way to "Compile and Save assembly" and then reference it from another script?  Or, is there a more direct way to cross reference between scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `#load` directive:

```
#load "Path\To\ScriptA.csx"

var t = new Thing();
```

You can read more about the C# script variant in the [Roslyn wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/Interactive-Window.md). Note that not everything there is relevant to RoslynPad, which unlike the C# Interactive window, is not a REPL.